# DBCtrlGrid with a DBLookupComboBox

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-7

Has anyone managed to get a `DBLookupComboBox` to work with a `DBCtrlGrid`?

A pre-filled in `DBComboBox` works ok, but it does not work too well for lookup tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't understand why it is forbidden action in Delphi, but i've managed to create my own lookup combo box component with `csReplicatable` flag in ComponentStyle and it works!

It's not thoroughly tested, but in my app it works without problems.

[Here is the source](http://snipt.org/qglj), check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Being quite reticent to alter/maintain altered VCL/RTL code, I found another way. Declare the following in the interface of your unit:

```
interface

uses
  ...
  ;

type Tdbp = class(TDBCtrlGrid);
type tdbl = class(TDBLookupControl);

type
  TForm4 = class(TForm)
    ...
    DBCtrlGrid1: TDBCtrlGrid;
    ...
  private
    ...
    function FindLCB(DataFieldName: String): TDBLookupComboBox;
    procedure FixDBLookupDataLinks;
  public
    ...
  end;



...and in your implementation:


----------


implementation

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...
  DBCtrlGrid1.DataSource := DataSource1;
  FixDBLookupDataLinks;
end;

procedure TForm4.FixDBLookupDataLinks;
var
  lcb: TDBLookupComboBox;
  I,n: Integer;
  MyDataLink: TDataLink;
  ctl: TControl;
  dbp: Tdbctrlpanel;
begin
  dbp := Tdbp(DBControlGrid1).Panel;
  for n := 0 to Pred(dbp.ControlCount) do
  begin
    ctl := dbp.Controls[n];
    if ctl.ClassType = TDBLookupComboBox then
    begin
      lcb := TDBLookupComboBox(ctl);
      lcb.ControlStyle := lcb.ControlStyle + [csReplicatable];
      TDBL(lcb).ListLink.DataSourceFixed := False;
      for I := 0 to Pred(lcb.ControlCount) do
      begin
        if lcb.Controls[I] is TPopupDataList then
        begin
          TDBL(lcb).ListLink.DataSourceFixed := False;
          TDBL(lcb).DataLink.DataSourceFixed := False;
          MyDataLink := TDataLink(lcb.Controls[I].Perform(CM_GETDATALINK, 0, 0));
          if MyDataLink <> nil then
            MyDataLink.DataSourceFixed := False;
            MyDataLink.DataSource := nil;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TForm4.FindLCB(DataFieldName: String): TDBLookupComboBox;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := Nil;
  for i := 0 to Pred(ControlCount) do
    if Controls[i].ClassType = TDBLookupComboBox then
      if TDBLookupComboBox(Controls[i]).DataField = DataFieldName then
      begin
        Result := TDBLookupComboBox(Controls[i]);
        Break;
      end;
end;
```

Comment: Could you please enrich your answer adding some explanation of your workaround or some comments in the source? It would be easier to realize if it's suitable for any personal use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround on [Embarcadero Developer Network](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=79869):

> I figured out how to work around the issue. Here is a sample. It
>   assumes that the combobox is placed on the grid at design-time, not
>   runtime. So at the moment the event handler is executing, the controls
>   have been streamed successfully from the DFM and links already
>   established. Though one should test in a real project.
>
> ```
> procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
> var
>   I: Integer;
>   MyDataLink: TDataLink;
> begin
>   for I := 0 to DBLookupComboBox1.ControlCount - 1 do
>     if DBLookupComboBox1.Controls[I] is TPopupDataList then
>     begin
>       MyDataLink := TDataLink(DBLookupComboBox1.Controls[I].Perform(CM_GETDATALINK, 0, 0));
>       if MyDataLink <> nil then begin
>         MyDataLink.DataSourceFixed := False;
>         MyDataLink.DataSource := nil;
>       end;
>     end;
> end;
> ```
>
> Andrei Fomine.

---

**If you have multiple `TDBLookupComboBox` on your `TDBGrid`**, you can use this snippet:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I, C: Integer; 
  curCombo: TDBLookupComboBox; curDL: TDataLink;
begin
  for C := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do begin
    if Components[C] is TDBLookupComboBox then begin
      curCombo:= (Components[C] as TDBLookupComboBox);

      for I := 0 to curCombo.ControlCount - 1 do
        if curCombo.Controls[I] is TPopupDataList then
        begin
          curDL := TDataLink(curCombo.Controls[I].Perform(CM_GETDATALINK, 0, 0));
          if curDL <> nil then begin
            curDL.DataSourceFixed := False;
            curDL.DataSource := nil;
          end;
        end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -2):

I just added a `TDBLookupCombo` to a `TDBCtrlGrid`. When I tried to set the `ListSource`, I got the error:

> Operation not allowed in a DBCtrlGrid.

Therefore it appears that this is explicitly forbidden in Delphi and so you won't be able to do it.